# Why aren't proceedings from ICM 2014 on mathscinet?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, mathscinet, conferences, icm-2014

Articles from the *Proceedings of the International Congress of Mathematicians*, Seoul, 2014 don't appear to be on Mathscinet. Why is this?

(Someone pointed this out to me recently, and I was reminded of it today when I tried to cite a lecture.)

Comment: One can ask the people at MathSciNet such questions directly. The answer is likely to be that they have not received review copies of the manuscripts. But asking these questions may lead them to request review copies again. I wrote to the executive editor just now. http://www.ams.org/publications/math-reviews/edcommandstaff

Answer (score 50, accepted):

We have had difficulty obtaining the requisite permissions from the publisher.  The ICM2014 website has the Legal Disclaimer: "The Seoul ICM Organizing Committee, the legal copyright owner of the articles in the proceedings, hearby grants unlimited noncommercial download and use of the articles."  This is not sufficient for our purposes.  The most recent communication with them was this week.  (Note: I'm the person @DanRamras wrote to.)

**Update (2018.02.22).**  We have now received permission from the publisher, as well as physical copies of the proceedings.  The papers are now in the database and available in MathSciNet.  Further processing (such as reviews) is still to come.  See [ICM2014, Volume I](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3727146), [ICM2014, Volume II](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3727147), [ICM2014, Volume III](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3727148), and [ICM2014, Volume IV](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3727149).

Comment: Nothing says "formal legal disclaimer" like misspelling "hereby".

Comment: Huh, I would not have guessed that MathSciNet listing would require the publisher's permission, since there is no copying of the article's content.  (Unless maybe it has to do with extracting the references?)

Comment: The material is copyrighted.  So we need to have permission to take a copy and do something with it.  In particular, we need permission to send a copy on to a reviewer.

Comment: You cannot send them a link to the official website, @EdwardDunne?

Comment: It's complicated, but the answer is no, we cannot just send them to the website.

Comment: @Edward yep, copyright is a complicated beast. (also, this case illustrates why just having something available on the internet is not great open acces, without further guarantees of usage rights)

Comment: @EdwardDunne: thank you very much for this information. I am glad to hear that efforts are being made. It seems to me that having these proceedings indexed (as is the case for past ICMs) is quite important for the mathematical community, and I hope the publisher agrees! Good luck with your efforts.

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson (and others):  I watch MathOverflow and try to spot references to Mathematical Reviews or MathSciNet.  However, you can always contact us directly at mathrev@ams.org or mrexec@ams.org (as in "EXECutive Editor").

Comment: Does the use by MathSciNet not qualify as "noncommercial"?

Comment: We are non-profit, but not non-commercial in many settings. In any case, it is a good practice to let people or publishers know ahead of time what we are planning to do.

Comment: I have updated my original answer with new information.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a comment, in community-wiki format to make it easier to compactify links.

To expand on Ed Dunne's reply, it may be helpful to note that each ICM organizing committee makes its own arrangements about formal publication of proceedings.   For the Seoul ICM see [*Seoul*](http://www.icm2014.org) and for PDF files of their four volumes of proceedings see [*here*](http://www.icm2014.org/en/vod/proceedings.html).   Presumably in due time all of this will be incorporated into the ICM site, where one can find older proceedings:  [*ICM*](http://www.mathunion.org/activities/icm).

Nowadays most people post earlier manuscripts on the arXiv, but of course they are more troublesome to track down.   In any case, the ICM databases of speakers and sessions are useful because published proceedings are usually organized into several volumes.